# Facebook SDK - LoginActivity - null pointer exception ANDROID

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am trying to make a login with facebook, and i have the problem.

When i press the button, facebook default login activity opens. When i press back, it goes back to the activity. I can try to login again, but when i switch orientation to landscape and go back, application crashes with this bug

11-15 09:48:48.249: E/AndroidRuntime(32063): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-15 09:48:48.249: E/AndroidRuntime(32063): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {org.eucila.activity/com.facebook.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-15 09:48:48.249: E/AndroidRuntime(32063):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2790)
11-15 09:48:48.249: E/AndroidRuntime(32063):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2819)
11-15 09:48:48.249: E/AndroidRuntime(32063):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
11-15 09:48:48.249: E/AndroidRuntime(32063):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3740)
11-15 09:48:48.249: E/AndroidRuntime(32063):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-15 09:48:48.249: E/AndroidRuntime(32063):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1262)
11-15 09:48:48.249: E/AndroidRuntime(32063):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-15 09:48:48.249: E/AndroidRuntime(32063):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-15 09:48:48.249: E/AndroidRuntime(32063):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-15 09:48:48.249: E/AndroidRuntime(32063):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-15 09:48:48.249: E/AndroidRuntime(32063):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-15 09:48:48.249: E/AndroidRuntime(32063):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-15 09:48:48.249: E/AndroidRuntime(32063):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-15 09:48:48.249: E/AndroidRuntime(32063):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-15 09:48:48.249: E/AndroidRuntime(32063): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-15 09:48:48.249: E/AndroidRuntime(32063):    at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.startOrContinueAuth(AuthorizationClient.java:135)
11-15 09:48:48.249: E/AndroidRuntime(32063):    at com.facebook.LoginActivity.onResume(LoginActivity.java:117)
11-15 09:48:48.249: E/AndroidRuntime(32063):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1192)
11-15 09:48:48.249: E/AndroidRuntime(32063):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5211)
11-15 09:48:48.249: E/AndroidRuntime(32063):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2780)
11-15 09:48:48.249: E/AndroidRuntime(32063):    ... 13 more

I have digged dipper, and it seems that after u go back, LoginActivity - onResume is called
and that calls AuthorizationClient method

```
   void startOrContinueAuth(AuthorizationRequest request) {
            if (appEventsLogger == null || appEventsLogger.getApplicationId() !=  request.getApplicationId()) {
                 appEventsLogger = AppEventsLogger.newLogger(context, request.getApplicationId());
           }

            if (getInProgress()) {
                continueAuth();
            } else {
                authorize(request);
            }
        }
```

This method gets request = null, and ofcourse application cannot continue. Now i ve read that this bug should of been fixed, but it isnt. So i wonder are there any solution to this, i cant even force this loginACtivity to be portrait mode, since its orientation still switches.
I am using facebook SDK 3.5.2

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are you sure you're using 3.5.2? This was fixed, and if you look at the code on Github, it's not the same as what you're showing above: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/AuthorizationClient.java#L134

Comment: Yes i thought so as well, i am using 3.5.2 and the problem still persists.. I Will try this 3.6.0 now :)

Comment: I have just tried this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/ It seems it fixes the issue, the login activity is now locked in portrait mode and when u come back the crash doesnt happen :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just tried this developers.facebook.com/docs/android It seems it fixes the issue, the login activity is now locked in portrait mode and when u come back the crash doesnt happen :)

Comment: There is just one more thing i have noticed, that this crash seems to come on some devices, and some not, for example this bug is still live on nexus7, but doesnt happen  on samsung galaxy tab and some others. So nothing to be done here. grrr..

Comment: You are right, while debugging on Nexus 4 i get user name however null pointer exception still occurs.